# I want to replace after WordPress is completely loaded

Tags: template-redirect

The replacement process is always done with the following code.
You can also use filter hooks, but some themes are hard-coded and you can't use filters.
So I'm using this code (template_redirect action) so that I can replace even hard-coded parts.

```
function my_replace_html($content) {

    $content = str_replace('<div class="aaa">',<div class="aaa bbb">', $content );
    return $content;

}
add_action('template_redirect', function(){ ob_start('my_replace_html'); });
```

However, this does not work for mobile themes set with the "Multi Device Switcher" plugin.

It has been replaced as usual with themes for PC.

HTML compression such as the "Autoptimize" plugin is also applied to the mobile theme set by the "Multi Device Switcher" plugin.

What's wrong with my method?

Comment: There is way too much stuff going on under the hood since you are talking about a lot of plugins and some 3rd party themes - not certain lines of code, which do not work. It's propably also something with wp_is_mobile(), or some custom functions of your themes and plugins. Who knows what "Multi Device Switcher" does. You have to figure out the functions, which produce the error and post this code here. First point of contact is the plugin/theme developer imo.

Comment: Thank you. I will contact the developer.